# Memory leak in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, memory-leaks, microsoft-metro

I've built my own control to mimic the VariableSizedGridView in Windows 8. Because that control does not support UI virtualization, I rebuilt it with virtualization. The control basically measures all the elements and calculates their positions, but only draws those that are in view. This makes for an enormous performance boost on the Surface RT.

There is one problem though, the control leaks memory. I'm sure that it's the control (or something related to it), as I've been able to reproduce the leak in an isolated app. The source code of the control is split in two classes. The `VirtualizedList` class is the base of the control, and defines a couple of DependencyProperties. The `VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid` class is where the magic happens and where the items are being drawn on the screen.

I'm not sure how I can fix this issue, as it's been happening for months now, and nothing I did helped. I checked my events, tried disposing the UI elements (which is unpossible, it seems). I guess the leak happens because some child elements of the DataTemplate are still bound to the data object, and thus still reference to them, and that's why the UI objects still stay in memory. I could be completely wrong though. As you can see in the code, when I update the view, I commented out `RemoveChild(old);`. That's because when I reuse old FrameworkElements (created from the DataTemplate), the leak goes slower. When I recreate new items all the time, the leak is about 5MB per scroll operation.

Any help on this would be *very much* appreciated! Thank you.

PS: Seems like I can not attach all source code. The VirtualizedList class only defines some DependencyProperties, so I'll leave that one out.

**Source**
*VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid*

```
[TemplatePart(Name="Root", Type=typeof(Grid))]
[TemplatePart(Name="Scroll", Type=typeof(ScrollViewer))]
[TemplatePart(Name="LayoutArea", Type=typeof(Grid))]
[TemplatePart(Name="SnappedView", Type=typeof(ListView))]
public class VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid : VirtualizedList
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SnappedItemContainerStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SnappedItemContainerStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null, SnappedItemContainerStyleChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListStateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListState", typeof(ViewState), typeof(VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid), new PropertyMetadata(ViewState.Full, ListStateChanged));

    private readonly List<object> _currentDataView;
    private Grid _root;
    private Panel _panel;
    private ScrollViewer _scrollViewer;
    private ListView _snappedView;
    private const double COLUMNS_PRELOADED = 2;
    private const double CARD_MARGIN = 6.0;
    private int _maxRows = 0;
    private object _selectedItem;
    private bool _moreDataRequested = false;

    public delegate void CalculatingItemSizeEventHandler(ItemContainer item);
    public event CalculatingItemSizeEventHandler OnCalculatingItemSize;
    public event SelectionChangedEventHandler SelectionChanged;
    public event EventHandler DataRequested;

    public enum ViewState
    {
        Full,
        Snapped
    }

    public VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid()
    {
        _currentDataView = new List<object>();
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid);
        this.Style = (Style) XamlReader.Load(
            @"<Style xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" xmlns:controls=""using:MeTweets.Controls"" TargetType=""controls:VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid"">
                <Setter Property=""Template"">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType=""controls:VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid"">
                            <Grid x:Name=""Root"" VerticalAlignment=""Stretch"" HorizontalAlignment=""Stretch"">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name=""Scroll"" ZoomMode=""Disabled"" HorizontalScrollMode=""Auto"" VerticalScrollMode=""Disabled"" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=""Hidden"" VerticalScrollBarVisibility=""Hidden"" HorizontalAlignment=""Stretch"" VerticalAlignment=""Stretch"">
                                    <Grid x:Name=""LayoutArea"" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <ListView x:Name=""SnappedView"" HorizontalContentAlignment=""Stretch""  HorizontalAlignment=""Stretch"" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>");

        this.Loaded += VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid_Loaded;
    }

    ~VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid()
    {
        this.Loaded -= VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid_Loaded;
    }

    #region Dependency Property Changed
    private static void SnappedItemContainerStyleChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid varSizeGrid = sender as VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid;
        if (varSizeGrid == null || !(e.NewValue is Style))
            return;

        varSizeGrid.SetupSnappedView();
    }

    private static void ListStateChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid varSizeGrid = sender as VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid;
        if (varSizeGrid == null || e.NewValue.Equals(e.OldValue))
            return;

        if (varSizeGrid.ListState == ViewState.Full)
        {
            varSizeGrid._scrollViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            varSizeGrid._snappedView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else if (varSizeGrid.ListState == ViewState.Snapped)
        {
            varSizeGrid._scrollViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            varSizeGrid._snappedView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        if (varSizeGrid.ListState == ViewState.Full)
        {
            var snapScroll = varSizeGrid._snappedView.FindFirstChildOfType<ScrollViewer>();
            if (snapScroll != null)
            {
                int index = (int)snapScroll.VerticalOffset;
                if (index >= 0 && index < varSizeGrid.ItemsSource.Count)
                    varSizeGrid.BringIntoView(varSizeGrid.ItemsSource[index]);
            }
        }
        else if (varSizeGrid.ListState == ViewState.Snapped)
        {
            if (varSizeGrid._itemContainer == null)
                return;

            var item = (from a in varSizeGrid._itemContainer
                        where (a.Column * varSizeGrid.ItemWidth) + varSizeGrid.ItemWidth > varSizeGrid._scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + varSizeGrid.Padding.Left
                        select a).FirstOrDefault();
            if (item == null)
                return;

            varSizeGrid.BringIntoView(varSizeGrid.ItemsSource[item.Index]);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Virtual Voids
    protected override void OnItemTemplateChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Item template changed");
        SetupSnappedView();
        GenerateItemContainers();
    }

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Items source changed");
        SetupSnappedView();

        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            if (e.OldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
            {
                INotifyCollectionChanged collection = (INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue;
                collection.CollectionChanged -= collection_CollectionChanged;
            }

            ClearItems();
        }
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            GenerateItemContainers();
            UpdateView();

            if (e.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
            {
                INotifyCollectionChanged collection = (INotifyCollectionChanged)e.NewValue;
                collection.CollectionChanged += collection_CollectionChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual DataTemplate GetDataTemplateForItem(object item)
    {
        return ItemTemplate;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public Style SnappedItemContainerStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(SnappedItemContainerStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SnappedItemContainerStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public ViewState ListState
    {
        get { return (ViewState)GetValue(ListStateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListStateProperty, value); }
    }

    public object SelectedValue
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _selectedItem)
                return;

            if (value == null)
            {
                _selectedItem = null;
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = _selectedItem;

            if (BringIntoView(value))
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                if (SelectionChanged != null)
                    SelectionChanged(this, new SelectionChangedEventArgs(new List<object>() { oldValue }, new List<object>() { value }));
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Overrides
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Debug.WriteLine("OnApplyTemplate");
        _root = this.GetTemplateChild("Root") as Grid;
        _panel = this.GetTemplateChild("LayoutArea") as Panel;
        _scrollViewer = this.GetTemplateChild("Scroll") as ScrollViewer;
        _snappedView = this.GetTemplateChild("SnappedView") as ListView;
        _snappedView.Loaded += _snappedView_Loaded;
        _scrollViewer.ViewChanging += _scrollViewer_ViewChanging;
        _scrollViewer.ViewChanged += _scrollViewer_ViewChanged;
        _panel.SizeChanged += _panel_SizeChanged;
        _snappedView.SelectionChanged += _snappedView_SelectionChanged;
        App.RootFrame.SizeChanged += RootFrame_SizeChanged;

        if (ItemsSource != null)
        {
            GenerateItemContainers();
            UpdateView();
        }
        SetupSnappedView();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private voids
    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        if (_panel == null)
            return;

        foreach (var item in _panel.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>())
        {
            RemoveChild(item);
        }

        _currentDataView.Clear();
        _panel.Children.Clear();
    }

    protected override void GenerateItemContainers()
    {
        if (_panel == null || _panel.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed || _panel.ActualHeight == 0 || _panel.ActualWidth == 0)
            return;

        _itemContainer.Clear();

        if (ItemsSource == null)
            return;

        int _currentRow = 0, _currentColumn = 0;
        int _currentColWidth = 1;
        _maxRows = (int)((_panel.ActualHeight-this.Padding.Bottom-this.Padding.Top) / this.ItemHeight);
        for (int ix = 0; ix < ItemsSource.Count; ix++)
        {
            var item = ItemsSource[ix];
            var container = new ItemContainer { Index = ix };
            if (_currentDataView.Contains(item))
                container.IsRealized = true;

            if (OnCalculatingItemSize != null)
                OnCalculatingItemSize(container);

            if (container.RowSpan < 0)
                container.RowSpan = 0;
            if (container.ColumnSpan < 0)
                container.ColumnSpan = 0;

            container.Column = _currentColumn;
            container.Row = _currentRow;

            if (container.RowSpan + _currentRow > _maxRows) //Not enough rows --> new column
            {
                if (_itemContainer.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Equally split the rest of the space in this column over the elements that are currently in it
                    var additionalrows = _maxRows - _currentRow;
                    var c = _itemContainer.Where(x => x.Column == _currentColumn).ToList();
                    var ccount = c.Count();
                    var i = 0;
                    foreach (var t in c)
                    {
                        t.Row += (additionalrows/ccount)*i;
                        t.RowSpan += additionalrows/ccount;
                        i++;
                    }

                    // Couldn't equally divide, give the rest of the space to the last element
                    if (additionalrows%ccount > 0)
                    {
                        c.Last().RowSpan += additionalrows%ccount;
                    }
                }

                _currentColumn++;
                container.Column = _currentColumn;
                _currentRow = 0;
                container.Row = _currentRow;
                _currentColWidth = container.ColumnSpan;
                _itemContainer.Add(container);
                _currentRow += container.RowSpan;
                continue;
            }

            //Make column as wide as widest element
            if (container.ColumnSpan > _currentColWidth)
                _currentColWidth = container.ColumnSpan;
            if (_currentColWidth > container.ColumnSpan)
                container.ColumnSpan = _currentColWidth;

            _currentRow += container.RowSpan;

            if (_currentRow >= _maxRows)
            {
                //Make sure all elements in column are as wide as widest element
                foreach (var wider in
                            _itemContainer.Where(x => x.ColumnSpan < _currentColWidth && x.Column == _currentColumn))
                {
                    wider.ColumnSpan = _currentColWidth;
                }

                _currentRow = 0;
                _currentColumn += _currentColWidth;
                _currentColWidth = 1;
            }

            _itemContainer.Add(container);
        }

    }

    protected override void UpdateView()
    {
        if (_panel == null || _scrollViewer == null || _itemContainer == null || _itemContainer.Count == 0)
            return;

        _panel.Width = ((_itemContainer.Last().Column + 1) * this.ItemWidth) + this.Padding.Left + this.Padding.Right;

        var margin = this.ItemWidth * COLUMNS_PRELOADED;
        double minLeft = (_scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset - margin);
        double maxLeft = (_scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + _scrollViewer.ActualWidth + margin);
        int minColumn = (int)(minLeft / this.ItemWidth)-1;
        int maxColumn = (int)(maxLeft / this.ItemWidth)+1;
        minLeft = (minColumn * this.ItemWidth) + this.Padding.Left;
        maxLeft = (maxColumn * this.ItemWidth) + this.Padding.Left;

        _currentDataView.Clear();
        var shown = _itemContainer.Where(x => x.Column >= minColumn && x.Column <= maxColumn);
        _currentDataView.AddRange(shown.Select(x => ItemsSource[x.Index]));

        List<FrameworkElement> recycle = new List<FrameworkElement>();
        foreach (var old in _panel.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>().Where(x => x.Margin.Left < minLeft || x.Margin.Left > maxLeft || 
            !(_currentDataView.Contains(x.DataContext))).ToList())
        {
            foreach (var recycled in _itemContainer.Where(x => ItemsSource[x.Index] == old.DataContext))
                recycled.IsRealized = false;
            //RemoveChild(old);
            recycle.Add(old);
        }

        foreach (var item in shown)
        {
            FrameworkElement obj = recycle.FirstOrDefault();
            double left, top;
            if (item.IsRealized)
            {
                //Rearrange item if needed
                obj = _panel.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)x).DataContext == ItemsSource[item.Index]) as FrameworkElement;
                if (obj == null)
                    continue;
                obj.Height = (this.ItemHeight * item.RowSpan) - (2 * CARD_MARGIN);
                obj.Width = (this.ItemWidth * item.ColumnSpan) - (2 * CARD_MARGIN);
                left = (item.Column * this.ItemWidth) + this.Padding.Left;
                top = (item.Row * this.ItemHeight) + this.Padding.Top;
                obj.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
                continue;
            }

            item.IsRealized = true;

            if (obj == null)
            {
                obj = this.GetDataTemplateForItem(item).LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
                obj.Tapped += Item_Tapped;
                obj.PointerReleased += Item_PointerReleased;
                obj.PointerEntered += Item_PointerEntered;
                obj.PointerExited += Item_PointerExited;
                _panel.Children.Add(obj);
            }
            else
                recycle.Remove(obj);

            obj.DataContext = null;
            obj.DataContext = ItemsSource[item.Index];
            obj.Height = (this.ItemHeight * item.RowSpan) - (2 * CARD_MARGIN);
            obj.Width = (this.ItemWidth * item.ColumnSpan) -  (2 * CARD_MARGIN);
            obj.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            obj.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            obj.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            left = (item.Column * this.ItemWidth) + this.Padding.Left; 
            top = (item.Row * this.ItemHeight) + this.Padding.Top;
            obj.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
        }

        foreach (var notRecycled in recycle) //Remove not recycled items
            RemoveChild(notRecycled);

        Debug.WriteLine("Children count "+_panel.Children.Count);
    }

    private void RemoveChild(FrameworkElement item)
    {
        item.Tapped -= Item_Tapped;
        item.PointerReleased -= Item_PointerReleased;
        item.PointerEntered -= Item_PointerEntered;
        item.PointerExited -= Item_PointerExited;
        _panel.Children.Remove(item);
        item.DataContext = null;
        item.ClearValue(DataContextProperty);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllProperties(TypeInfo type)
    {
        var list = type.DeclaredProperties.ToList();

        var subtype = type.BaseType;
        if (subtype != null)
            list.AddRange(GetAllProperties(subtype.GetTypeInfo()));

        return list.ToArray();
    }

    public List<DependencyObject> AllChildren(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        var list = new List<DependencyObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child != null)
                list.Add(child);
            list.AddRange(AllChildren(child));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private void SetupSnappedView()
    {
        if (_snappedView == null)
            return;

        _snappedView.ItemTemplate = this.ItemTemplate;
        _snappedView.ItemContainerStyle = this.SnappedItemContainerStyle;
        _snappedView.ItemsSource = this.ItemsSource;

        var snapScroll = this._snappedView.FindFirstChildOfType<ScrollViewer>();
        if (snapScroll != null)
        {
            snapScroll.ViewChanged -= snapped_ViewChanged;
            snapScroll.ViewChanged += snapped_ViewChanged;
        }
    }

    private void Item_PointerExited(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Item_PointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private bool _pointerPressed = false;
    private object _pointerOriginalSource = null;
    private void Item_PointerReleased(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Handled)
            return;

        _pointerPressed = true;
        _pointerOriginalSource = e.OriginalSource;
    }

    private void Item_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_pointerPressed || e.OriginalSource != _pointerOriginalSource)
        {
            _pointerPressed = false;
            return;
        }

        object previousObject = _selectedItem;
        object dataObject = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;

        if (dataObject != _selectedItem)
        {
            _selectedItem = dataObject;
            if (SelectionChanged != null)
                SelectionChanged(this, new SelectionChangedEventArgs(new List<object>() { previousObject }, new List<object>() { dataObject }));
        }

        _pointerPressed = false;
    }

    void collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        object item = null;
        if (_itemContainer != null && _itemContainer.Count > 0 && ListState == ViewState.Snapped)
        {
            var snapScroll = _snappedView.FindFirstChildOfType<ScrollViewer>();
            if (snapScroll != null)
            {
                int index = (int)snapScroll.VerticalOffset;
                if (index >= 0 && index < ItemsSource.Count)
                    item = ItemsSource[index];
            }
        }
        else if (_itemContainer != null && _itemContainer.Count > 0 && ListState == ViewState.Full)
        {
            var i = (from a in _itemContainer
                        where (a.Column * ItemWidth) + ItemWidth > _scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + Padding.Left
                        select a).FirstOrDefault();
            if (i == null)
                return;

            item = ItemsSource[i.Index];
        }

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            _moreDataRequested = false;

        GenerateItemContainers();
        UpdateView();

        //if (item != null)
        //    BringIntoView(item);
        //else if (this.ItemsSource is IList && (this.ItemsSource as IList).Count > 0)
        //    BringIntoView((this.ItemsSource as IList)[0]);
    }

    void VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ListState == ViewState.Full)
        {
            this._scrollViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this._snappedView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else if (this.ListState == ViewState.Snapped)
        {
            this._scrollViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this._snappedView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("VirtualizedVariableSizedWrapGrid Loaded");
        if (this.ItemsSource != null && (_itemContainer == null || _itemContainer.Count == 0))
        {
            GenerateItemContainers();
            UpdateView();
        }
    }

    void snapped_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is ScrollViewer))
            return;

        var scroll = (sender as ScrollViewer);
        var maxOffset = scroll.ExtentHeight - scroll.ViewportHeight;
        if (!_moreDataRequested && (maxOffset <= 0 || scroll.VerticalOffset >= maxOffset))
        {
            _moreDataRequested = true;
            if (DataRequested != null)
                DataRequested(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    void _snappedView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var snapScroll = this._snappedView.FindFirstChildOfType<ScrollViewer>();
        if (snapScroll != null)
        {
            snapScroll.ViewChanged += snapped_ViewChanged;
        }
    }

    private double _lastOffsetUpdate = 0;
    void _scrollViewer_ViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NextView.HorizontalOffset == e.FinalView.HorizontalOffset)
        {
            UpdateView();
            return;
        }

        if (Math.Abs(e.NextView.HorizontalOffset - _lastOffsetUpdate) > 100)
        {
            _lastOffsetUpdate = e.NextView.HorizontalOffset;
            UpdateView();
        }
    }

    void _scrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_moreDataRequested && this._scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + this._scrollViewer.ActualWidth >= (this._panel.ActualWidth))
        {
            _moreDataRequested = true;
            if (DataRequested != null)
                DataRequested(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    void _panel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int currentMaxRows = _maxRows;
        _maxRows = (int)((_panel.ActualHeight - this.Padding.Bottom - this.Padding.Top) / this.ItemHeight);
        if (_maxRows != currentMaxRows) //Orientation probably changed, control got higher
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Panel size changed");
            ClearItems();
            GenerateItemContainers();
            UpdateView();
        }
    }

    void _snappedView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            this.SelectedValue = e.AddedItems[0];

        _snappedView.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    void RootFrame_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_itemContainer != null && _itemContainer.Count > 0 && _panel.ActualWidth > 0)
            UpdateView();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public voids
    public override bool BringIntoView(object obj, bool animate = true)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (_itemContainer == null || _itemContainer.Count == 0)
                return false;

            var item = (from a in _itemContainer
                        where ItemsSource[a.Index] == obj
                        select a).FirstOrDefault();
            if (item == null)
                return false;

            //Calculate position
            double offset = (item.Column * this.ItemWidth) + CARD_MARGIN;
            this._scrollViewer.ChangeView(offset, null, null, !animate);
            _snappedView.ScrollIntoView(obj, ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading);

            UpdateView();

            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Many times it's easier for us to find the problem if you boil the code down to be [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In many cases that exercise can even help you find the answer on your own!

Answer (score -2):

Do you set `ContentTemplate` and/or `Style` for containers somewhere? Or maybe another properties such as `BorderBrush` etc? Maybe you do that in xaml?

If you do, try to set all these properties to `null` when releasing the container. It helped me in some memory leak cases.

Comment: I downvoted because this aint no answer. Even if it leads him to get rid of the leak, this are just a bunch of speculations which don't even lead to a proper solution. I agree that his code is too long, but how is that relevant to the leak? The long code makes it harder to detect the problem but this should be the first time that "long code" results in leaks.

Comment: as you want. To get actual leak you need complete solution. From his code you only can see that he unsubscribed from everything he could. But the leak might be out of there. Do you think that there are true magicians here to get rabbit from the hat?
And if you can read, my answer is not about long code

Comment: But he 's sure the leak is in this control. I understand ur point, but its not an answer (it's a bunch of try this or try that). This information can be useful, but use the commenting system imo. Don't get me wrong, I didn't downvote coz I like to downvote. And Idd your actual "answer" isn't about too long code, but ur starting with it (at least mention the reason why too long code is relevant with his question: e.g. long code makes it harder to locate the leak). But again, this aint no answer. If I would have the same issue as the OP has, looking at your answer wouldn't help me in any way.

Comment: believe me, there are no easy answers about this. And there are tons of similar questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259433/how-to-detect-memory-leaks-in-c-sharp-application. My answer is about my experience with similar leaks in similar controls. If he is lucky it would help. If not, google about profiling and debugging, make assumptions and check them with proper tools. Might take a long-long time